# Why do I need that line? (C#)

Tags: c#

I need help understanding why do I need this line in the following code, and what does it do:

```
this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
```

If I don't add that line, the saving never happens. It's like the code in the Form1_FormClosing function doesn't execute, and thus the program always start with the default value. But I never had to use anything like this for other events such as buttonclicks etc. They worked fine without it. Why is this one different?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Location = Settings.Default.WindowLocation;
    this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
}
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default.WindowLocation = this.Location;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Btw sorry about this stupid question, but I don't know anything about C#(or programming...). I just wanted to write a simple GUI for my program. And it works perfectly now after I found out I need this line... I would just like to understand why.

Comment: its all about decision. its an event that fires when the form is closing.i think it will save the work

Comment: [Events tutorial MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)...

Comment: "They worked fine without it" - No, take a look into the designer code - you will find the eventhandler there. The line similar to your this.FormClosing are written by the forms designer and you can see it if you look "behind" the scene (the files like *.Designer.cs)

Comment: It is defined like that for all the other events too. It's usually defined in the <formname>.designer.cs file

Comment: oh you are right, they are all there, except for the closing which I had to add manually... I feel so stupid now... Thanks for the answares though!

Comment: it is adding new event to form closing!!

Comment: it is adding new event to form closing!! that might be calling the saving functions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FormClosing event occurs just before a form is closed, either by the user, through the user interface (UI), or programmatically, through calls to methods such as Close in the Form class, or Exit in the Application class. This event can be canceled.

When you create a FormClosingEventHandler delegate, you identify the method that will handle the event. To associate the event with your event handler, add an instance of the delegate to the event. The event handler is called whenever the event occurs, unless you remove the delegate.

A delegate in C# is similar to a function pointer in C or C++. Using a delegate allows the programmer to encapsulate a reference to a method inside a delegate object. The delegate object can then be passed to code which can call the referenced method, without having to know at compile time which method will be invoked. Unlike function pointers in C or C++, delegates are object-oriented, type-safe, and secure.

A delegate declaration defines a type that encapsulates a method with a particular set of arguments and return type. For static methods, a delegate object encapsulates the method to be called. For instance methods, a delegate object encapsulates both an instance and a method on the instance. If you have a delegate object and an appropriate set of arguments, you can invoke the delegate with the arguments.

An interesting and useful property of a delegate is that it does not know or care about the class of the object that it references. Any object will do; all that matters is that the method's argument types and return type match the delegate's. This makes delegates perfectly suited for "anonymous" invocation.

A delegate can be seen as a placeholder for a/some method(s).

By defining a delegate, you are saying to the user of your class "Please feel free to put any method that match this signature here and it will be called each time my delegate is called".

Typical use is of course events. All the OnEventX delegate to the methods the user defines.

Delegates are useful to offer to the user of your objects some ability to customize their behaviour. Most of the time, you can use other ways to achieve the same purpose and I do not believe you can ever be forced to create delegates. It is just the easiest way in some situations to get the thing done.

Refrence from [FormClosingEventHandler MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx), [Delegate MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx)