# Calling a Pre-Shut Down Function in C#

Tags: c#, function

I have a function

```
public void preShut()
    {
        saveLastPoint(DataTable A);
        saveShutVoltage (DataTable A);
        saveVehicleState (DataTable vStates);
    }
```

I want to call this function in an event of Closing of Application window (either Alt+F4 or using Mouse Click)
Only after this function is called my application shall shut Down.
Can anyone suggest a method to do it?

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    if (string.Equals((sender as Button).Name, @"CloseButton"))
        // Do something proper to CloseButton.
    else
        // Then assume that X has been clicked and act accordingly.
}
```

I got this solution but could not understand it.

Comment: Can I get an explanation or only down votes?

Comment: There is no pre-event for an Alt+F4 scenario. If the user closes the application via X button, you can do it. Otherwise, I suggest you do what every other software does for such scenario - auto saves by intervals.

Comment: I suspect that people would want to see code of or at least read a description what you have tried so far.

Comment: @YoryeNathan are you sure about that? Does not cancelling the `FormClosing` event work for alt+f4?

Comment: @Jite Actually OP is showing some code but wants to know where to invoke it. No reason to downvote from my point of view.

Comment: @Jite You made me doubt it, but there is always killing the process as a way to bypass the event for sure.

Comment: @HimBromBeere (I did not downvote) The code he is (was after edit) showing is not really relevant to the question. Any code which invokes the method would be.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Oh yes, of course, terminating it via the Task manager or similar would most likely not fire the event.

Comment: @Jite Seems like Alt F4 does indeed fire up that event. But I believe that if the program is not responsive and you spam Alt F4, it will eventually close it in a more violent fashion ('Close now' dialog, etc)

Comment: I did not understand the reason of downvote also. There is nothing to show here. I just wanted the event to be used. @HimBromBeere thanks. Stackoverflow is brutal on beginners, rememeber its foe help of everyone not only seasoned programmers.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to make sure that youre hitting this,  the comments above are right that if you close through task manager that this will not fire,  so you might want to use a timerEvent to periodically save any unsaved data, but put some breakpoints in your code and test each closing senario and see what hits your breakpoints and add he line of code to hit your method to save your data then use something like `Environment.Exit(0)` to close the application gracefully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using WinForms than there is already an event defined for it

[**FormClosing**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx): The FormClosing event occurs as the form is being closed. When a form is closed, it is disposed, releasing all resources associated with the form. If you cancel this event, the form remains opened. To cancel the closure of a form, set the Cancel property of the FormClosingEventArgs passed to your event handler to true.

and in case you are using WPF then also we have an event for it

[**Closing**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx): Closing can be handled to detect when a window is being closed (for example, when Close is called). Furthermore, Closing can be used to prevent a window from closing. To prevent a window from closing, you can set the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs argument to true.

You can also use Delegate for this You can read [my previous answer for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32391643/3796048)

Comment: Thanks for your in depth explanation. This is a model answer.